# How do I host Express static site plus API in single Azure Web App

Tags: javascript, azure, express, azure-web-app-service

I have what I thought was an extremely simple Express app. In fact, I stood it up and got it running on my laptop in less than an hour. It's deploying to Azure Web App that is driving me nuts!

I have a simple/static web app that also has its own API. So, requests to /website.com/api are handled as API (basically, forwarded to a different server to avoid CORS issues) and everything else is served from a static site area.

This is the entire Express App:

```js
import express from 'express'
import fetch from 'node-fetch'
const app = express()

const API_SERVER_URL = 'https://my-web-site.com/'

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Express listening at port 3000'))
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(express.json({ limit: '1mb' }))

app.post('/api', async (request, response) => {
  const paramStrArr = request.originalUrl.split('?')
  const paramStr = paramStrArr.length > 1 ? '?' + paramStrArr[1] : ''
  const results = await fetch(API_SERVER_URL + paramStr, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      "Content-type": 'text/plain',
      "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(request.body)
  })
  const responseBody = await results.text()
  response.send(responseBody)
})

app.get('/api', async (request, response) => {
  const paramStrArr = request.originalUrl.split('?')
  const paramStr = paramStrArr.length > 1 ? '?' + paramStrArr[1] : ''
  const results = await fetch(API_SERVER_URL + paramStr, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      "Content-type": 'application/json',
      "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
    }
  })
  response.send(await results.text())
})
```

This works perfectly when I run from localhost. Static content renders. API calls work great!

In fact, as the rest of the Web App is basically a static site in the public folder, that seems to be about the only part that's relevant to this problem. No security. Nothing in the least bit complex about this...or so I thought.

After deploying to Azure Web App, the static pages load and display great (i.e. my-web-site.com/ returns expected HTML page)! But any POST or GET to my-web-site.com/api/ returns a 404 error.

My guess is that Azure's server is looking for a ./api/ folder (and/or corresponding index.html), finds none and returns the 404 - instead of routing the request through my root index.js.

I've found old Azure docs on redirecting, but the instructions are outdated and don't seem to apply here (i.e. literally cannot be followed due to now-missing options, etc). I expected some way to do this in the console (i.e. in Web App settings/config/networking); but I've not found anything.

I've tried creating a web.config to redirect calls. But if this is the solution, I'm doing something wrong. I can share that - if needed - but I'd like someone to verify that I'm headed in the right direction first. I suspect I'm missing something pretty simple.

Answer (score 1):

Can you update the static middleware registration to:

```
var path = require('path');


app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Here we are explicitly defining the route /static (or whatever name you prefer) for static contents.

It's bit strange, the working sample from https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-web-nodejs-get-started just works fine for me.

Comment: Thank you for your quick suggestion. However, this did not have the desired effect. It made no difference. localhost continues to work. But the Azure deployed site behaves the same. i.e. my-site.com/ displays the correct web page by ./API/ calls return 404. All good on localhost.

Comment: Sure I can! Good suggestion. But the static content was already rendering correctly. This change had no effect on my problem. Static content still renders fine. ./API/ calls still give 404 error. Seriously... thank you for your continued suggestions. I'm willing to try anything.

Comment: yeah it's bit strange, the working example link I shared just runs fine for me. Also, note in my updated answer, I am now registering an explicit virtual route for static files. So, now /static/.. serves only static files and /api/.. serves api requests.

Comment: I'll try the linked app as a baseline - right down to putting static content in a different folder. I was reluctant since it's 5 years old. But if you got it working, it looks like it's worth a shot. I'll flag the above response as an answer if it works. Thank you!

Comment: I am not suggesting to move to different folder. /static is just a virtual path, your folder is still "public". https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: Part of my problem must be in the deployment. So far, I've been using automatic builds through Azure Repos/Pipeline. The noted GIT repository doesn't work. It complains because "npm run build" doesn't work. I get an "error: missing script: build". Can you point me to something on the process you used to deploy?

Comment: I generally deploy following similar to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/javascript?view=azure-devops&tabs=code . (ignore the mocha for now, that's for unit test anyway)

Comment: Also, another way to deploy is direct integration with git from web app like https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/create-a-nodejs-site-deploy-from-github/

Comment: My problem is with the deployment itself. My problem is that the referenced git repo doesn't include a build script. When I try any of the deployment methods, I get an error that it couldn't "npm run build." Still searching...

Comment: In the package.json `"scripts"` section, add `"build": "echo \"Just dummy build script to avoid build error in Azure pipeline\""`